# How to fix the errors changing compileSdkVersion from 28 to 29

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Changing **compileSdkVersion** from **28 to 29** produce build time error
**Elvis operator (?:) always returns the left operand of non-nullable type String**
In this line **private val _tag: String = this::class.java.simpleName ?: "ABCD"** but the same is working perfectely below **29**.
I am using following versions :
**compileSdkVersion 29, minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 29, build_tools_version = '29.0.2'**,
**gradle_version = '3.2.0', kotlin_version = '1.3.50'**
This is only one example of error. I am getting such a type of 68 error in my project so it is very hard for me to fix these errors and test it. I am feeling there is something short way to fix these errors or i am missing something.

Comment: This is probably a Lint error. The best solution is to get rid of the `?: "ABCD"`, as that is unnecessary and is a waste of space. But, if you are getting the Lint error in Android Studio, you could see if there is a quick-fix for `SuppressLint`. If so, you could suppress it for your whole module via the `lintOptions` closure in your module's `build.gradle` file, using the value passed to `@SuppressLint` as the value to put in your `disable` Lint options.

Comment: I have not used linOptions before can you give me one example of lint for the above error.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#config